# What do D and +-- mean in chess annotation?

Tags: notation, annotation

When using Stockfish to annotate some of my games, I will often get the symbols D and +--,  which I can't find definitions for. I think that +- means “decisive advantage” for White, and that +-- might mean “very decisive.” As for D next to a move I am at a loss.

Comment: Maybe it is ++- instead of --+?  That would be a move that gives a check and results in a position with evaluation +-

Answer (score 4):

"D" means see diagram. "+/-" means white is better, but not much better.

Comment: Hmm so what diagram is it referring to if it is just an annotated pgn? And also is +/- the same as +--? I was substantially better at that point like approx +7.

Comment: There is software that prints annotated games.  the D tells it to produce a diagram for that position.

Comment: D in human written forms can mean also a draw offer

Comment: @TheNightman In order, `+--` `+-` `+/-` `+=` indicate progressively smaller advantages for White.